# Switch оператор . Для чего некоторые пишут break за пределами case?

Tags: c++

Например:

```
bool var= true;
switch(var)
{
case(true):
{
// some actions
}
break;
}
```

Дело ли это вкуса или все же есть какие то примеры где именно такое использование break сыграло бы какую то иную роль?

Comment: Возможно, скобки были вставлены для ограничения области видимости переменной, объявленной внутри. Тогда все что должно выполниться после ее деструктора - за скобками, включая break.

Comment: @Chorkov Но если `break` внутри скобок, то он сам вызовет деструктор переменной. Так что разницы быть не должно.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat разумеется, можно и внутри и снаружи. Речь об акцентировании внимания читающего.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нет никакой разницы.

> break за пределами case

Но вообще, вопрос странно поставлен.

Фигурные скобки - это не границы `case`. Их там может не быть вообще, или может быть несколько пар. Даже сам `case` может быть во вложенных фигурных скобках.

---

Еще, круглые скобки в `case(true):` не нужны.

Comment: еще и для типа    bool, принимающих всего два значения,  нет смысла  в конструкции  switch

Answer (score 3):

У `case` нет никаких "пределов". Все "тело" `switch` - это один непрерывный statement, обычно (но не обязательно) составной, т.е. заключенный в `{}`. Метки `case` - это просто метки, т.е. точки входа в этот statement. По сути своей они ничем не отличаются от меток `goto`.

В "теле" `switch`, вперемешку с метками `case`, вы можете писать что угодно, в том числе вводить вложенные блоки `{}`, чьи границы никак не будут согласованы с расстановкой меток `case`. А можете не вводить никаких вложенных блоков вообще. В вашем примере совершенно не важно, где будет поставлен этот `break` - за пределами вложенного блока или внутри него.

Язык С++ лишь запрещает вам "прыгать" в область видимости автоматической переменной, пропуская ее объявление, если это объявление выполняет инициализацию. Это правило в одинаковой степени распространяется на переходы `goto` и на переходы `switch/case`.

Comment: По мне ТС хотел знать есть ли пример, где возник бы необходимость вложенного блока

Answer (score 1):

В данном случае `break` не находится *за пределами* `case`.

Конструкция исторически пришла из C, где она интерпретировалась, как набор меток и операторов `goto`.

Рассмотрим пример.

```
switch (i) {
  case 1:
     . . .
     break;

  case 2:
     . . .
     break;

  case 3:
     break;
}
```

Он означает.

```
label1:
  . . .
  goto end;

label2:
  . . .
  goto end;

label3:
  . . .
  goto end;

end:
```

Адреса меток 1, 2 и 3 хранятся в массиве и компилятор вставляет быстрый код, который пробегается по этому массиву, сравнивает `i` с каждой константой и переходит на нужный адрес, если значение совпадает.

Именно поэтому нельзя использовать в качестве переменной сложные константы, например строковые. Только примитивные типы, которые сравниваются одной инструкцией процессора.

И именно поэтому ветки `case` могут *слипаться* без `break`.

```
case 1:
case 2:
  . . .
  break;

base 3:
  break;
```

Теперь посмотрим на фигурные скобки. Кажется, что они обязательно должны быть *приклеены* к операторам `if`, `while` или `switch`, но это не так. Фигурные скобки это всего лишь способ сделать *блок операторов*, их можно вставлять в любом месте, где может стоять один оператор.

```
int a = 1;
float b = 2.72;

{
  printf("%d\n", a);

  b = 3.14;
  printf("%f\n", b);
}
```

Это вполне корректный код, хотя так писать не принято.

Вложенный блок позволяет переопределить переменную из внешнего блока.

```
int i = 100;

{
  int i = 50;
  printf("%d\n", i);
}

{
  int i = 70;
  printf("%d\n", i);
}

printf("%d\n", i);
```

Мы получим 50, 70 и 100. Чтобы использовать переменную с одним и тем же именем внутри разных веток `case`, можно делать там блоки:

```
case 1:
  int a = 100;
  . . .
  break;

case 2:
  int a = 200;
  . . .
  break;
```

Этот код не будет компилироваться, потому что переменная `a` два раза определена в одной и той же области видимости. Если добавить фигурные скобки, код будем компилироваться.

```
case 1:
  {
    int a = 100;
    . . .
  }
  break;

case 2:
  {
    int a = 200;
    . . .
  }
  break;
```

Я бы лично так писать не стал, поскольку фигурные скобки усложняют структуру кода для восприятия, и, как вы заметили, запутывают читателя.

Comment: Этот код не будет компилироваться в первую очередь потому, что метки `case` "перепрыгивают" через инициализацию переменной `a`, а не потому, что переменная `a` определена два раза. Вы можете оставить всего одно определение `int a = 100;`, но исходный код все равно не будет компилироваться. В первую очередь именно *эту* проблему решает дополнительный блок.

Comment: Я хотел бы отметить этот ответ плюсом, но нужно сначала внести поправку, учитывая комментарий выше